# how to pass variable to controller from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

```
$(function(){
$('#textb').keypress(function (e) {
 var key = e.which;
 var messag=document.getElementById('textb').value;
 if(key == 13) 
  {
 window.location.href = "refresh/?mesag=" + messag;
  }
});
});
```

how to pass variable to controller from view in codeigniter

Comment: give us full code will check better solution. And don't forget to explain your question with **What happens** and **What you need**

Comment: well we don't pass variable from view to controller but from controller to view

Answer (score 0):

View:

```
 if(key == 13){
    $.post( "route/to/post/to", { id: "2"} );
 }
```

Controller:

```
if($this->input->post("id")){
    echo $this->input->post("id");
}
```

This will echo 2